# copy multiple files in storage bucket using list

Tags: python, pandas, google-cloud-storage, dask, gsutil

The `gsutil cp` command hast the [`-I` option](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp#options) to copy multiple files using a list of file names from `stdin`. Is there a way to do the same in python, preferable using a library like the official [google storage client](https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/client.html) or [gcfs](https://gcsfs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#)/[fsspec](https://filesystem-spec.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)? Or is it only possible to iterate over all the file names and copy each one?

Comment: According to the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/renaming-copying-moving-objects#copy) it's not possible to copy multiple files with the google cloud storage client python library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the version currently in `gcsfs` master (to be released soon), you can copy files to GCS from memory or local files with a list:

```
gcs.pipe({path1: content1, path2, content2})  # for in-memory bytes

gcs.put([local_path1, local_path2], [remote_path1, remote_path2])  # files
```

For the latter, you can give just one remote path, which will be assumed to be a directory, and the remote files will get the same basenames as local.

The calls will be processed concurrently, which may be much faster than sequential uploads, especially for small transfers.

Comment: Thanks @mdurant for your help! Is it also possible to use `gcs.put` with remote paths? I think of a call like the following `gcs.put([remote_path1, remote_path2], [remote_path])`. If this is not possible, what would be the required steps to use `gcs.cp` with a list of file names?

Comment: `cp` also allows multiple files using a list (the second argument would be a string not be a list, though, unless you want to specify the exact filename for every target) - that's what you are after if you are doing GCS->GCS.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I'd like to do. Could you please provide a working example of this? When I try this with `gcsfs` version 0.6.2: `fs = gcsfs.GCSFileSystem();
fs.copy(file_names, "gs://bucket/path")` I get > AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'rstrip'. Am I missing something or should I use the latest master of `gcsfs`?

Comment: Only on master, coming in version 0.7.0

Comment: Thanks @mdurant! Do you have a rough estimate of when 0.7.0 will be released?

Comment: This week. https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/35655 needs to go in before s3fs/gcsfs releases, so that pandas doesn't break. I'll merge gcsfs alone, if that PR is taking too long.